# Как сделать вертикальное меню с функциею прокрутки к нужному разделу страницы ?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Например, как на этом [сайте](http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/docs/#data) (меню с правой стороны).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Azsv5/

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    font: 14px/20px tahoma;
}
nav {
    background-color: #f9fbfc;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #fff, #f1f5f7);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #b6c9d4;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 38px;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 180px;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}
nav li {    
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none outside none;    
}
nav .current a, nav a:active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f1f5f7;
    border-collapse: separate;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}
nav a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #b6c9d4;
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #3780aa;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover { 
    background: rgba(55, 128, 170, 0.149);
    text-decoration: none;
}

div{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding: 20px 10px 0;
    width: 350px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){
        var anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 0
    }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#link1">download</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link2">examples</a></li>   
      <li><a href="#link3">documentation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link4">source</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="link1">
    <p><strong>Раздел 1</strong></p>    
</div>

<div id="link2">
    <p><strong>Раздел 2</strong></p>   
</div>

<div id="link3">
    <p><strong>Раздел 3</strong></p>    
</div>

<div id="link4">
    <p><strong>Раздел 4</strong></p>    
</div>
```

Comment: @soledar10, если нужно подраздел, как сделать ? http://jsfiddle.net/Titan93/Azsv5/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u7LEk/

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не нужна анимация, а только прокрутка до нужного места, то значит, что вы прогуливали "[первые уроки первой четверти по самым основам HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/name)"

**Обновление**

Сейчас нет особо времени на создание чего-то более нового, поэтому посмотрите [такое старенькое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/YQrn2/), которое я делал для аналогичной задачи.

Comment: @Deonis, возможно я не совсем правильно задал вопрос, мне нужно такую навигацию как на этом сайте: http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/docs/#data-xMin не понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо)